# Definition of a connection on a principal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to understand the definition of a connection as given in, for example, Taubes' book *Differential Geometry*. Let $\pi: P \to M$ be a principal bundle with a $G$ action. He states that a connection is a linear map

$A: P \to ker(\pi_\ast)$.

He states further that $A$ can be viewed as a map

$P \to lie(G)$

through an isomorphism $\psi: P \times_g lie(G) \to ker(\pi_\ast)$, with the following properties:

1. $A(\psi(p,g)) = g$,
2. If $g \in G$ and $v \in TP$, then $A((m_g)_\ast v) = g A(v) g^{-1}$, where $(m_{g})_\ast$ is the push-forward of the action of $g$.

My first question is, why is $\psi$ an isomorphism? Second, how do these operations look in coordinates? Third, I think this leads to the relationship

$g.A =   dg \ g^{-1}+ g A g^{-1}$

that shows up when one considers gauge transformations, how is this so? I have some amount of riemannian geometry experience behind me, but this abstraction is a bit puzzling and hard to get my fingers on. Examples would be welcomed, so that I have something that I can get my hands on.

Comment: First, your action should have $g^{-1}$ on the right in both terms. Second, I think you'll find that it's $P\times_G\mathfrak g$, not the direct product. Coordinates is not the way to go, although I'm more used to doing all this with differential forms. But it's hard to give a whole course in an answer here, especially not knowing what you've studied/learned to this point.

Comment: I think I fixed the two issues. In Friedman and Morgan's book *Gauge Theory and the Topology of 4-Manifolds* the connection is a form, and I think the two properties are there stated in terms of a right action and the pull-back of a right action. Why should one not think about these constructions in coordinates? What is a better way to look at them? Do you suggest differential forms?

Comment: Just write everything in coordinates where $\nabla = d + A$ ($A$ is the matrix of Cartan forms) and glue everything using the cocycles of the bundle. Then you will see the gauge transformation.